# How to find the value range of a function with multiple intervals in the definition domain?

Tags: functions

```
FunctionRange[(2 Sqrt[3] (k^2 + 1))/(
 3 k^2 - 1), {k, k > 1/Sqrt[3], k < -1/Sqrt[3]}, y]
```

The above function argument has two interval ranges  k > 1/Sqrt[3], k < -1/Sqrt[3]. How do I find the value range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FunctionRange[{(2 Sqrt[3] (k^2 + 1))/(3 k^2 - 1), 
  k > 1/Sqrt[3] || k < -1/Sqrt[3]}, k, y]
```

> `y > 2/Sqrt[3]`